# What to do (besides rebooting) when Finder won't navigate to /tmp?

Tags: finder

If one uses the `Command + Shift + G` keyboard shortcut and asks Finder to navigate to `/tmp`, on occasion instead of being taken to `/private/tmp` (with appropriate hiding of the `/private` directory from the user) the user is taken to `/` as exhibited here:

[image: attempting to navigate to <code>/tmp</code>]

And if I attempt to navigate to `/private/tmp`:
[image: attempting to navigate to and open <code>/private/tmp</code>]

What gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer appears to be related to `setfile`. If one runs `getfileinfo /private/tmp`:

```
Tomass-MacBook-Pro:tmp tomasgallucci$ getfileinfo /tmp
directory: "/private/tmp"
attributes: avBstclinmedz
created: 07/30/2016 14:32:36
modified: 01/16/2017 14:56:52
Tomass-MacBook-Pro:tmp tomasgallucci$
```

In my case, the bundle flag was turned (capital letters mean attributes are turned on, lower case means they're turned off). To resolve the issue I was able to run

```
setfile -a b /private/tmp
```

And I could once again navigate to `/tmp` in Finder.

What set the Bundle bit? I don't know. But life wouldn't be worth living if there weren't at least a few mysteries.

Here's a [Super User article](https://superuser.com/questions/461571/guis-treat-tmp-as-a-file) that discusses the topic in some detail.

Answer (score 0):

Logging out your user will recycle Finder without needing to reboot. That will show you if the issue is a temporary bug or more permanent permissions issue with the file system.

Comment: How about trying `killall -HUP Finder` instead of logging out?

Comment: @user3439894 I dislike killing Finder - file operations in progress, etc... at best, use AppleScript to ask Finder to quit. Log out is my proper suggestion - especially for online or when the (file?) system is already misbehaving or broken.

Comment: @user3439894 Finder can also be restarted from the "Force Quit Applications" window. `Command+Option+Esc` can open it quickly. While restarting Finder might not be the best option as mentioned by @bmike, this is a quicker way than using the terminal.

Comment: I tried rebooting my MBP and that solve the problem for a matter of hours. I'm not sure what turned the Bundle flag back on; my guess is that it had to do with trying to upload an .epub from /tmp to Google Drive.